# reading unstructured txt file into dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a kind of messy text file with the same data repeated all after 15 min
i want to create a data frame from that txt file using python

with open(fname) as f:
    content = f.read().splitlines()

```
2019-09-26 14:15:44 discount=1e
019-09-26 14:16:44 discount=4e
019-09-26 14:17:44 discount=2e
019-09-26 14:18:44 discount=3e
019-09-26 14:19:44 discount=2e
some text
some text
some text 
Products: sold = 5, bought = 5, left = 0 (20% profit),
New data and new data in the same format
```

> Expected dataframe

```
date                     discount    profit
2019-09-26 14:15:44         1          20%
2019-09-26 14:16:44         4          20%
2019-09-26 14:17:44         2          20%
2019-09-26 14:18:44         3          20%
2019-09-26 14:19:44         2          20%
```

Comment: Use regex to filter out the interesting lines and then convert it to a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

This works with your sample data but you may need to tweak some things with your real data.

Data:

```
2019-09-26 14:15:44 discount=1e
2019-09-26 14:16:44 discount=4e
2019-09-26 14:17:44 discount=2e
2019-09-26 14:18:44 discount=3e
2019-09-26 14:19:44 discount=2e
some text
some text
some text 
Products: sold = 5, bought = 5, left = 0 (20% profit),
2019-09-26 14:20:44 discount=1e
2019-09-26 14:21:44 discount=4e
2019-09-26 14:22:44 discount=2e
2019-09-26 14:23:44 discount=3e
2019-09-26 14:24:44 discount=2e
some text
some text
some text 
Products: sold = 5, bought = 5, left = 0 (15% profit)
```

In:

```
# range(12) because the expected input was 12 fields. May need to change this to the number of expected fields    
df = pd.read_clipboard(names=[x for x in range(12)]) 

# 10 is the column name with the profit.  May need to change this.
df[10] = df[10].bfill()

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df[0] +' '+ df[1], errors='coerce')
df = df[df['date'].notnull()]
df['discount'] = df[2].str.strip('discount=e')
df['profit'] = df[10].str.strip('()')

df[['date', 'discount', 'profit']]
```

Out:

```
|         date        | discount | profit |
|:-------------------:|----------|--------|
| 2019-09-26 14:15:44 | 1        | 20%    |
| 2019-09-26 14:16:44 | 4        | 20%    |
| 2019-09-26 14:17:44 | 2        | 20%    |
| 2019-09-26 14:18:44 | 3        | 20%    |
| 2019-09-26 14:19:44 | 2        | 20%    |
| 2019-09-26 14:20:44 | 1        | 15%    |
| 2019-09-26 14:21:44 | 4        | 15%    |
| 2019-09-26 14:22:44 | 2        | 15%    |
| 2019-09-26 14:23:44 | 3        | 15%    |
| 2019-09-26 14:24:44 | 2        | 15%    |
```